# Integral of the Product of two Sech functions

Tags: calculus, integration

Assume 
$$
u(x,t_n,x_n) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2t_n}} \operatorname{sech}\left( \frac{x - x_n}{t_n} \right)
$$
I know that

$$
\int dx\;u ( x,t_n,x_m )\;u ( x,t_n,x_n ) = \frac{1}{2} \operatorname{csch}\left( \frac{x_m - x_n}{t_n} \right) \ln \left( \frac{\cosh \left( \frac{x - x_n}{t_n} \right)}{\cosh \left( \frac{x - x_m}{t_n} \right)} \right) + c
$$

But I want to calculate this integral for different $t_n$ and $t_m$ and obtain a close relation, i.e.
$$
\int dx\;u ( x,t_m,x_m ) \;u ( x,t_n,x_n) =\ ?
$$

Can any one help me?

Thanks

Comment: In both this question and the answer by @GEdgar, the style of MathJax code is bizarre and it's hard to imagine it serving any purpose but to make editing difficult.  See my edits.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample from Maple:
$$
\int \!\text{sech} ( x ) \text{sech} ( 1/3\,x ) \,dx=
\\
\frac{2\left( 4\sqrt {3}\arctan \left( \frac {\sqrt {3}\sinh
 ( 1/3 x ) }{\cosh ( 1/3\,x ) } \right) 
 ( \cosh ( 1/6 x ) )^2 - 2 \sqrt {3}\arctan
 \left( \frac {\sqrt{3} \sinh ( 1/3 x ) }{\cosh ( 1/
3 x ) } \right) -3 \sinh ( 1/6\,x ) \cosh ( 1
/6 x )  \right) }{3\left( 2 ( \cosh ( 1/6 x ) )^2 - 1 \right)}
$$

Comment: Thanks, I also have obtained a closed form for other value of $t_m$ for example $t_m=2t_n$, $t_m=3t_n$ and ..., but I want a close relation for arbitrary $t_m$ and $t_n$.

Answer (score 0):

For tm=tn, I do not arrive to your formula. Instead of (1/2) I have tn as a front multiplicator. If I derive your formula, I do not obtain your integrand.

For the case you ask, I do not think that a closed form could be obtained but I can be wrong. Whatever I tried sent me to nowhere.

Comment: Excuse me, you are completely right. I took a mistake and I forgot to write the factor $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 t_n}}$. I edit the $u(x,t_n,x_n)$ function.

Comment: @MojtabaGolshani. If tm and tn are not independent (say than one of them is amultiple of the other), things could be done. The same if tm is very close to tn.